# How to cut the first n bytes from the body in a camel blueprint?

Tags: java, apache-camel, blueprint-osgi

I am routing and transforming some data with [apache camel](http://camel.apache.org/) and want to cut the first n bytes of the body. So I will transform the body by reading the stream except the frist n bytes. Is there a smart way to do this in a camel blueprint?

Comment: What do you mean by camel-blueprint? Do you mean you will now write a java class and 5 lines of code, but you want to only write something in the xml file to do this?

Comment: Hey @ClausIbsen - exactly. I try to find a way with pure xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague gave me a good hint and I think this is the answer I was looking for:

```
<convertBodyTo type="byte[]"/>
<transform>
    <spel>#{T(java.util.Arrays).copyOfRange(body, n, body.length)}</spel>
</transform>
```

where n is the number of bytes I want to cut from the start of the ByteArrayOutputStream. I think this is a solution, isn't it?

Certainly you have to build some checks and ExceptionHandling around it, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for this out of the box. It depends a bit which java object type is holding the data, i.e. is it a InputStream or byte[] or a String or something else.

And do you need to skip a fixed number of bytes every time, or does it depends? And what if there is less bytes than the number? i.e. you end up with more complicated logic that is better to write some java code to handle properly.

If you really must use XML then you can try inlining groovy and use Camels groovy language which you can use from the blueprint xml file.

Comment: The body is a ByteArrayOutputStream and it is a fixed number of bytes I have to skip every time. To handle the case that there could be less then n bytes is a good idea!